# what does 'practice' mean in 'this practice can lead to burnout'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I wrote the sentence. I have a feeling that I can use 'practice' to refer to the italic text. However, after checking the dictionary, I still don't know exactly what 'practice' means in this context. Does it mean 'activity'?

> I disagree that *employers should provide their employees with at least
> four weeks of vacation every year*, because **this practice** can lead to
> burnout for those who remain at work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, in that context it means the practice (or policy) of employers providing at least four weeks of vacation to their employees.

[COLLINS COBUILD Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/practice) sense 1 looks like a good fit:

> You can refer to something that people do regularly as a **practice**.
>
> - Some firms have cut workers' pay below the level set in their contract, a practice that is illegal in Germany.
> - The Prime Minister demanded a public inquiry into bank practices.
>
> Synonyms: *custom*, *use*, *way*, *system*